# If the value of an uninitialized variable shouldn't affect the value of an expression, is it still UB?

Tags: c, initialization, undefined-behavior

This is a follow-on from [a discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7268089/how-is-xyz-evaluated/7268193#7268193), which I think deserves a question of its own.

Basically, is the result of this undefined?

```
int x;
int y = 1 || x;
```

There are two "common-sense" arguments here:

1. Mathematically speaking, no matter what the value of `x`, the value of `y` should be `1`.
2. Because of short-circuiting, `x` is never evaluated anyway.

But the counterargument is that we have an expression that involves an uninitialized variable, so all bets are off (in theory).

More generally, if the value of an uninitialized variable can't possibly affect the result of an expression, is it "safe"?  e.g.:

```
int x;
int y = x - x;
```

**Usual disclaimer:** Of course, I'm not advocating ever writing code like this.

Comment: The behaviour of the expression isn't so much as undefined, but what the compiler might do in optimisation remains undefined. In this case though, it will probably just drop the x.

Comment: Note that `x = 1` is "an expression that involves an uninitialized variable". So whoever offers that counter-argument is going to have to be a bit more precise what they think is disallowed, unless they're saying that `int x; x = 1;` is UB because `x` is uninitialized!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In C, it is undefined behavior to use the value of an object with automatic storage duration while it is indeterminate. (J.2, informative) but it's OK for variables with automatic storage duration to hold an indeterminate value.

An expression can only have its value used if it is evaluated and according to 6.5.12 (Logical OR operator) the second operand is not evaluated (let alone have its value used) if the first operand compares unequal to 0.

Answer (score 6):

<sup>***Disclaimer:*** I thought the question was for C++ as well. Apparently it is for C only. I don't speak C-standardese, but I believe my answer holds true for C as well, although using different termiology</sup>

```
int x;
int y = 1 || x;
```

is well defined because x is simply not evaluated - guarantee of short-circuit evaluation of ||.

```
int x;
int y = x - x;
```

invokes undefined behvior, because x is evaluated and ***an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion takes place***. If that conversion didn't take place, the behavior would be well-defined, for example:

```
int x;
int* y = &x;
int z = &x - &x;
```

Here x is also evaluated but no lvalue-to-rvalue conversion takes place, so it's defined.

Comment: You argument would appear to apply to C++, not C. C doesn't use the term _rvalue_ or have an _lvalue-to-rvalue conversion_.

Comment: Is the concept of "lvalue-to-rvalue conversion" derived from the standard?

Comment: @Oli: Yes, it is. But I must admit I don't seem to find the relevant quote right now

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: The _lvalue-to-rvalue conversion_ is an explicitly defined C++ concept. C doesn't use the term rvalue, it uses "value of an expression" instead (according to a note to 6.3.2.1). The value of an expression is determined when an expression is evaluated. From 6.5.14 (Logical OR operator): "If the first operand compares unequal to 0, the second operand is not evaluated."

Answer (score 2):

Regarding `y = x - x;`, one worst-case scenario to bear in mind is that an uninitialized variable might contain a trap value.

You can't rely on the presence of an optimizer to realise that `x - x` doesn't actually depend on the value of `x`, and so certainly the implementation is allowed to use the value of `x` in evaluating `x - x`, and it's used in the abstract machine.

So if it's a trap value, you'd have a hardware error or whatever the implementation does when it traps. UB, anyway.

I remember that one system I used added extra guarantees about the behavior of indeterminate values. It stated that using an indeterminate value would not explode, but also was not required to behave as if the value was any actual value of the type. So, `x-x` would result in another indeterminate value, not necessarily 0. This is actually *less* useful than trapping, since it stores up the programming error for later use when you least expect it, but AFAIK it's completely conforming since behaviour is not defined by the standard.

Comment: Note that the common case INT_MIN = -2^(CHAR_BIT*sizeof(int)-1) guarantees the nonexistence of trap representations, so from a practical standpoint I believe it's more important to realize that the compiler is given specific permission by the standard to generate nonsense code when an indeterminate value is used.

Comment: @R..: I try to do both where possible - have in mind a conforming implementation that would do something odd for an understandable reason, as "rationale" and a mnemonic for the fact that UB is permitted. And then of course understand that since behavior is undefined, any implementation can do any crazy thing for any reason, understandable or otherwise. It's true though that the UB is permitted simply because an indeterminate value is used, there's no necessity that the indeterminate value be capable of holding a trap value, so it is just a prod towards understanding rather than a proof.

Answer (score 1):

> Basically, is the result of this undefined?
>
> `int x; 
>   int y = 1 || x;`

Nopes! `x` is never **used**/ **evaluated**.

`int y = x - x;` invokes UB.